# What is a Calabi-Yau space?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, definition, mathematics, calabi-yau

I had trouble understanding [Calabi-Yau space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) while reading the theory of strings and how it works in this theory. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: A dedicated text (or chapter of a book) on the application of Calabi-Yau spaces in string theory would probably solve your problems.

Comment: Is there anyone who does not have trouble understanding Calabi-Yau space? How much trouble are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

An n-dimensional Calabi-Yau manifold is an n-dimensional complex-Kahler manifold with trivial [canonical bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_bundle). The triviality of the canonical bundle implies the existence of a global nowhere zero section on its spinor bundle (the square root of the canonical bundle). The physical importance of that condition is that the above spinor section can be used to define local supersymmetry generators, or in other words, consistent supersupersymmetric (tachyon-free) string theories can be defined over Calabi-Yau manifolds.

See [The String Landscape, the Swampland, and the Missing Corner](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00864)
 (page 7) to learn further details and to understand the role of special holonomy manifolds in supersymmetri field/string theories.

References:

[String theory on Calabi-Yau manifolds](https://cds.cern.ch/record/321108/files/9702155.pdf)

[Why string theory predicts supersymmetry](https://motls.blogspot.com/2010/06/why-string-theory-implies-supersymmetry.html)